# How to make a redirection link open in new tab

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this following code to make a post redirect to a custom URL in WordPress:

```
add_action ('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
function custom_redirect() {
global $post;
  if( is_single() ){
    $external_link =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'external_link', true );
    if($external_link) {    
       wp_redirect( $external_link );
       exit;
    }
  }
}
```

But my site breaks when I add **target="_blank"** to the 5th line. I am adding it like this:

```
$external_link =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'external_link', true, target="_blank", );
```

But it is now working.

I just want the external links to open in new tab.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "But it is now working.", did you meant to say "But it is not working"? If so - please state 'how' it is not working

Comment: I need my links to open in new tab. I have added target blank as I have mentioned above. But it is showing syntax error when I visit my site.

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript `window.open` instead of `wp_redirect`.
Please try following code.

```
add_action ('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
function custom_redirect() {
  global $post;
   if( is_single() ){
      $external_link =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'external_link', true );
      if($external_link) {  
         echo "<script> window.open(".$external_link.", '_blank') </script>";
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some precisions... Referring to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/, there's no "target" parameter. That's why you get an error. Wordpress codex can give you a lot of answers, especially when you decide to invent some parameters.
There's no target parameter for wp_redirect. That's why you can't user wp_redirect.
In this case, javascript is your friend, as Bhunesh Satpada wrote it.